# Powershell compare one array as substring of another array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a text file domains.txt

```
$domains = ‘c:\domains.txt’
$list = Get-Content $domains

google.com
google.js
```

and an array

```
$array = @(".php",".zip",".html",".htm",".js",".png",".ico",".0",".jpg")
```

anything in $domain that ends in something in @arr should NOT be in my final list

So google.com would be in final list but google.js would not.

I found some other stackoverflow code that give me the exact opposite of what I'm looking for but, hah I can't get it reversed!!!!

This gives me the exact opposite of what I want, how do I reverse it?

```
$domains = ‘c:\domains.txt’
$list = Get-Content $domains

$array = @(".php",".zip",".html",".htm",".js",".png",".ico",".0",".jpg")

$found = @{}
$list | % {
    $line = $_
    foreach ($item in $array) {
        if ($line -match $item) { $found[$line] = $true }
    }
}

$found.Keys | write-host
```

this gives me google.js I need it to give me google.com.

I've tried -notmatch etc and can't get it to reverse.

Thanks in advance and the more explanation the better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `.`s off, mash the items together into a regex `OR`, tag on an end-of-string anchor, and filter the domains against it.

```
$array = @("php","zip","html","htm","js","png","ico","0","jpg")


                # build a regex of
                # .(php|zip|html|htm|...)$

                # and filter the list with it
$list -notmatch "\.($($array -join '|'))`$"
```

Anyway, the simple way to invert your result is to walk through `$found.keys | where { $_ -notin $list }`. Or to change your test to `$line -notmatch $item`.

But beware that you are doing a regex match and something like `top500.org` would match `.0` and throw your results out. If you need to match at the end specifically, you need to use something like `$line.EndsWith($item)`.

Comment: god, regex is a nightmare, how do you master that? ^.^

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am nowhere near a master of it, but knowing something about the way it is a state machine really helps. See what it does here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/MKHbIUS-LTadXlbl
 matches a dot, then branches trying to match any of those branches, then comes back together after to try and match the special end of string character. And see it here https://regex101.com/r/lxPAUx/3 with a step by step explatian on the right - and click the regex debugger on the left and it walks through the steps it's taking.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler big ups for the answer and even more so the links and explanation in your comment!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I tried $found.keys | where { $_ -notin $list }. Or to change your test to $line -notmatch $item and it still wouldn't work.  The regex seems to do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
$array = @(".php",".zip",".html",".htm",".js",".png",".ico",".0",".jpg")
get-content C:\domains.txt | where {[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_) -notin $array}
```